# Can not set price for In-App-Purchases items in iTunesConnect

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, non-renewing-subscription

I am trying to create in-app-purchase for my app in iTunesConnect, and every things works fine, but the only problem is to set a price for this item, I'm using **Non-Renewable-Subscription**, and pricing section keeps loading for ever.
[image]

Do i need to do something to fix it? or  Is it a bug in iTunesConnect? or  Can't we set a price for **Non-Renewable-Subscription** ??

Comment: Just try to wait a little and try again. If they didn't gave your any error, then it's probably issue with their server

Comment: Same from my side, waiting for Apple to fix this, have already sent them issue request.

Comment: Same here since a few days ago.

Comment: The problem here, I tried another account and it works well, so I don't think it is a server issue